# Choosing python client lib for Cassandra

Tags: python, cql, cql3, pycassa, python-db-api

I have worked with Pycassa before and wrote a wrapper to use batch mutation & connection pooling etc. But http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions recommends now to use CQL 3 based api because Thrift based api (Pycassa) will be supported for backward compatibility only. Apache site recommends to use Python api written by DataStax which is still in Beta (As per their documentation). See warnings from their python-driver/README.rst file

**Warning**

This driver is currently under heavy development, so the API and layout of packages,modules, classes, and functions are subject to change. There may also be serious bugs, so usage in a production environment is *not* recommended at this time.

DataStax site http://www.datastax.com/download/clientdrivers recommends using DB-API 2.0 plus legacy api's. Is there more? Has any one compared between CQL 3 based apis? Which stands out on top? Answers based on facts will help the community so please refrain from opinions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an older question, and in the meantime there has been a lot of development done on the [DataStax Python driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver). This is probably the best choice today because it's the most active and up to date (with support for CQL3, for example, as you mentioned).

The [Pycassa](https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa) author is also recommending a switch:

> pycassa does not support CQL or Cassandra's native protocol, which are
>   a replacement for the Thrift interface that pycassa is based on. If
>   you are starting a new project, it is highly recommended that you use
>   the newer DataStax python driver instead of pycassa.